# Hide field when click thumbnail using css or js

Tags: javascript, css

I need to hide some option when clicking the thumbnail, for the thumbnail HTML code

```
<div class="editor_thumbnail">
                        <ul id="side-switcher"> 
                        <li class="thumb"><img data-target="0" src="img1" alt="" class="tooltip img_switcher img d_block tooltipstered"></li><li class="thumb"><img data-target="1" src="img2" alt="" class="tooltip img_switcher img d_block tooltipstered"></li></ul>
                    </div>
```

for the first field

```
<div data-target="front" class="front" id="front"><label for="front">FRONT</label><textarea maxlength="100" data-area="front" class="text" data-target="front" id="front" placeholder="front texthere!">Front text!</textarea></div>
```

second field

```
<div data-target="back" class="back" id="back"><label for="back">Back</label><textarea maxlength="100" data-area="back" class="text" data-target="back" id="back" placeholder="back text!">Back Text!</textarea></div>
```

when I click the front thumbnail it will only show front field likewise with the back thumbnail,

I can not change HTML code because the code already in there, I try to use css like tab but still fail, i want to use onclick but the html code not have onclick.

Comment: So what did you tried so far?

Comment: i try to use CSS like tab function but still fail, because i cannot change HTML code I cannot add onclick

Answer (score 0):

Using **Javascript** you can add attributes to your HTML elements by using `setAttribute()`:

```
function addAttributes() {
  // Element.setAttribute(name, value);
  document.getElementById('myElement').setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction();');
}
```

**A detailed explanation on `setAttribute()` can be found on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) MDN page.**

I also wanted to point out that `IDs` must be unique - I noticed you used the same ID value for your `div` tags as well as your `textarea` tags.